# Handle cancelation inside Kotlin Coroutines producer

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Is it possible to handle producer cancelation inside producer builder itself? It could be useful to unsubscribe from callback:

```
private fun changes(key: String) = produce<Unit>(UI, CONFLATED) {
        val listener = OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener { _, changedKey ->
             if (key == changedKey) offer(Unit)
        }
        prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener)
        ???.onCancel { 
                 prefs.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener)
        }
}
```

Or may be exists another way to implement this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should not use `produce` builder to adapt API with listeners in this way, because on the exist from the `produce` builder body the channel is immediately closed and would cease to serve its function. Instead, you should just create a `Channel()` and create the corresponding connections.

Unfortunately, channels do not currently provide an out-of-the-box way to install cancellation listeners (see [issue #341](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/341)). The only way to get immediately notified on the channel close is to extend the corresponding channel class, which leads to the following code:

```
private fun changes(key: String): ReceiveChannel<Unit> = object : ConflatedChannel<Unit>() {
    val listener = OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener { _, changedKey ->
        if (key == changedKey) offer(Unit)
    }

    init {
        prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener)
    }

    override fun afterClose(cause: Throwable?) {
        prefs.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener)
    }
}
```

Comment: `ConflatedChannel` seems to be `internal`, so we cannot use it...

Answer (score 2):

An upcoming version of the kotlinx.coroutines library [should expose a `Channel.invokeOnClose { ... }` method](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/341#issuecomment-400274888) to satisfy such use cases.

However, there are solutions to have this behavior in the meantime.
One solution is to [subclass the channel you're looking for, as Roman Elizarov suggested.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51041980/4433326)

Another solution is to use produce the following way:

```
fun SharedPreferences.changes(key: String) = produce {
    val changesChannel = ConflatedChannel<Unit>()
    val listener = SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener { _, changedKey ->
        if (key == changedKey) changesChannel.offer(Unit)
    }
    registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener)
    try {
        for (change in changesChannel) {
            send(change)
        }
    } finally {
        unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's workable solution, but It looks like using `produce` in this case isn't semantically correct. It just a lot of overhead which doesn't help in any way.

Comment: I can tell you that the code above works the way you want it, [I used the same approach for a BLE scanning channel](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/341#issuecomment-384660210).

The overhead is not much there, you use one additional channel, and that's it. If you're really concerned about this, I'd encourage you to profile your project and see if this poses a significant performance/efficiency issue over other things that could be optimized in the codebase. ;-)

Anyway, the upcoming `invokeOnClose { ... }` method will be the best solution.

Comment: Although you do end up listening to your SharedPreferences potentially for a while after your channel as been closed, if nothing changes, don't you? If nothing is pushed on the inside channel (by the listener), nothing is sent on the outer one, so you never detect that it has been closed.